# SquirrelMail and VAdmin

Tags: postfix, squirrelmail

Recently install SquirrelMail on an Amazon EC2 micro instance. The client requires administrative access - so have installed and set up the - [VAdmin Plugin](http://squirrelmail.org/plugin_view.php?id=3).  However, there appears to be hardly any documentation.

In the `vadmin/conf` directory I have created the sql.conf.php file - however there are a lot of predefined SQL queries like for example>

```
vadmin_get_all_usernames_for_domain_query = SELECT username FROM email_users WHERE domain = '$1' $2 ORDER BY username
```

Q. is - how do you create these tables like `email_users` above - is there a certain structure to follow? There's no make files or anything, are there any SQL create queries out there for VAdmin or SquirrelMail? Not sure where these queries have been built from.. Do I make my own?

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone comes across this - just adapted the SQL to fit my tables, and it works well - cheers

Comment: How did you adapt it and what did you exactly do? I'm about to install it now on a squirrel mail installation.